# C# double/decimal always have two decimals

Tags: c#

I need 45.7 to be 45.70

Math.Round(d, 2) have no effect.
Have tried with decimal and double type.

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: A number (of whatever numeric type) is never going to have extraneous 0s - they mean nothing. You have to convert it to a string.

Comment: The values `45.7` and `45.70` are the same. Actually the value is not stored in that form at all, but in the form `(1 + 0.428125) * 2 ^ 8`, it only looks like `45.7` when you format it into a decimal number to display it.

Comment: @neminem It is not actually true that a number of the decimal type "is never going to have extraneous 0s".  Try this, for example: `Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", 1m, 1.00m);`  (Of course, that doesn't help answer this question, since it is clear that the OP's needs to understand string formatting, as you suggest.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a string format:

```
string.Format("{0:N2}", 45.7)
```

Check here for docs on the [string formatters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)